# Cannot assign to read only property '_events' of object when calling mint() on a ERC721 contract

Tags: ethers.js, nft

I am trying to call mint() on a ERC721 contract which accepts two parameters: `_address` & `tokenURI`. I have the following code which I am calling from frontend:

```
const mintNFT = async (tokenURI)=>{
  state.isMinting=true;
  const contractAddress = import.meta.env.VITE_SMART_CONTRACT_ADDRESS;
  const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress,contractABI.abi,snap.signer);
  debugger;
  try {
    const mint = await contract.mint(snap.walletAddress,tokenURI);
    await mint.wait();
    console.log("minted successfully!! ");
    state.isMinting=false;
    state.isMinted=true;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error while minting! ",error);
    state.isMinting=false;
  }
}
```

But I am getting error when `contract.mint()` is called. I am getting this error, `Cannot assign to read only property '_events' of object '#<Web3Provider>`

Currently I am using ethers.js v^5.7.2

I don't know why I am getting this error. May anyone know why I am getting this error?

Deployed Smart contract (verified): https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x1604Fef32d056bB14035056A12d78EBd9706680E

Thanks